# New-AzureADMSGroupを用いた動的グループの作成

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph, microsoft-teams

PowerShellを使ってMS365の動的グループを作成することを目指しています。
公式の[リファレンス](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadmsgroup?view=azureadps-2.0)に記述がある例を使って動的グループを作成することが出来ません。
ご教授をお願いしたいです。

```
PS C:\> New-AzureADMSGroup -DisplayName "Dynamic Group 01" -Description "Dynamic group created from PS" -MailEnabled $False -MailNickName "group" -SecurityEnabled $True -GroupTypes "DynamicMembership" -MembershipRule "(user.department -contains ""Marketing"")" -MembershipRuleProcessingState "On"
```

これについて、以下のようなエラーが出ます。

```
New-AzureADMSGroup : パラメーター名 'membershipRule' に一致するパラメーターが見つかりません。
```

リファレンスに記述があるにも関わらず、AzureADでは動的グループを作成することができないのではないかと疑っています（ExchangePowerShellを使う必要あり？）。

Answer (score 0):

AzureAD モジュールと AzureADPreview モジュールのどちらをお使いでしょうか。membershipRule をサポートしているのは AzureADPreview のようです。もし AzureAD モジュール を利用されているようであれば、AzureADPreview モジュールをお試しいただけますでしょうか。

参考：https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/34263#issuecomment-510978402